# SQL LIKE matches int when variable is varchar(4) but not varchar

Tags: sql-server-2008

Trying to match some records to users by user ID (an int).  But it will be done dynamically and I need to be able to match all records at the same time (I pass a '%' char for a LIKE wildcard).  I have done this before and came across this problem accidentally.

```
Declare 
   @uid varchar = 300

SELECT * FROM items WHERE user_id LIKE @uid
```

Does not work, but this does

```
Declare
   @uid varchar(10) = 300

SELECT * FROM items WHERE user_id LIKE @uid
```

It matches fine,
why does the first version not work when the size of the varchar is not declared?  Why does it not throw an error?

Environment is MSSQL SERVER 2008 R2

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : declaring VARCHAR without (length)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On behalf of everyone who will later have to maintain your code, please don't.

The reason varchar does not work is because that would be equivelent to `varchar(1)` - one character wide.  That being said, if you want to allow retrieval of everything or one user, try the following:

```
DECLARE @Uid int
-- Get user id 300
SET @Uid = 300
-- Will match on 'User_ID = @Uid'
SELECT * FROM Items WHERE (User_ID = @Uid or @Uid is null) OPTION (RECOMPILE)
-- Get all users
SET @Uid = null
-- Will match on '@Uid is null'
SELECT * FROM Items WHERE (User_ID = @Uid or @Uid is null) OPTION (RECOMPILE)
```

Using `LIKE` requires the server to convert every row you are filtering to a string, then do a string comparison, all but forcing a table scan.  Using `=` with `is null` will cause the processor (hopefully) to notice that `@Uid is null` evaluates to `true` regardless of row.

---

Per the recommendation of Martin Smith, I ended up looking into it a bit more, and found a much more complete [discussion of the subject by MVP Erland Sommarskog](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search-2008.html).  Long and short, be sure to include `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` to avoid sub-optimal plan selection.  There are caveats to that advice, and I would recommend you read the article to avoid getting caught by them – I'm off fix some underperforming search SPs...

Comment: Thanks, would not have expected it to default to varchar(1), it seems that it would make more sense to default to varchar(255) on undeclared size.  Also thanks for tip on "is null"

Comment: +1 You will still get the scan problem with `WHERE (User_ID = @Uid or @Uid is null)` except if you add an `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` in there though.

Comment: @MartinSmith, thanks, that's a new one for me.  I will have to look in to that.